# extended update in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, sql-update

I have a table named 'products' and another table named 'rates' that has one to many relation with 'products' table. For each product i have two rows in 'rates' table that i want update one boolean column named 'index' to 1 for each 'product' in 'rates' table.

i used this query :

```
UPDATE  ( SELECT 
             products.id AS productId,
             products.name ,
             X.`index` AS `index`, 
             x.id AS rateId, 
             x.price, x.discount

          FROM products JOIN ( SELECT rates.* 
                               FROM rates 
                             ) AS x

                WHERE products.id = x.product_id
                GROUP BY products.id
            ) AS y
SET y.index = 1
```

but id got this error massage:

> SQL Error (1288) the target table y of the update is not updatable

i'm new in mysql and i don't know where is my mistake.Thank you for helping

Products Table

```
| id  |  name    
| 1   |  chair
| 2   |  bench
```

Rates Table

```
| id  |  product_id  | index | value
|  1  |       1      |   0   |   xx   ==> index = 1
|  2  |       1      |   0   |   yy
|  3  |       2      |   0   |   zz   ==> index = 1
|  4  |       2      |   0   |   tt
```

i want update index column for each product in rates to 1

Comment: The purpose of your query is quite unclear. Which table do you want to update, and under which condition? Please provide sample data and desired results to clarify your question.

Comment: I updated my post @GMB

Comment: Thanks @ali. What is the logic to decide which rows in `rates` get `index = 1`?

Comment: i'm just creating fake data for my web application :) @GMB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to `update` the "first" row in `rates` for each `product_id`. If so, you can self-join the table with an aggregate query that computes the minimum `id` per `product_id`:

```
update rates r
inner join (select product_id, min(id) id from rates group by product_id) r1 
    on r1.id = r.id
set r.index = 1
```